# Use JSX when using react loaded by <script> tag on html page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

Is this possible to **use JSX** attributes, **without bundler**? (just using a HTML which is loading react in  tag)

index.html file:

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js file:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Content</div>;
  }
}

const e = React.createElement;
const domContainer = document.querySelector("#root");
ReactDOM.render(e(App), domContainer);
```

Comment: Very low effort question. The first page of the installation instructions on official docs tell you that this is possible and how to do it. https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: agreeing with @nbokmans . first important lesson is to read the docs carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a *transpiler*, not a bundler. You *can* run one client-side, but shouldn't because it introduces performance problems (and can make it harder to debug your code).

This is covered in [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#quickly-try-jsx):

> The quickest way to try JSX in your project is to add this `<script>`
> tag to your page:
>
> ```
>  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
> ```
>
> Now you can use JSX in any `<script>` tag by adding
> `type="text/babel"` attribute to it. Here is an example HTML file with
> JSX that you can download and play with.
>
> This approach is fine for learning and creating simple demos. However,
> it makes your website slow and isn’t suitable for production. When
> you’re ready to move forward, remove this new `<script>` tag and the
> `type="text/babel"` attributes you’ve added. Instead, in the next
> section you will set up a JSX preprocessor to convert all your
> `<script>` tags automatically.